# MY lstm has a really low accuracy, is there anyway to improve it?

Tags: python, keras, time-series, lstm, rnn

I am trying to make a model to classify whether these patients can be diagnosed with dementia by their 35 days of biometric data.

A brief summary of a dataset is below.

as an input X_train data, it has 51 features and 148 user IDs. And collect 35 days of biometric data from patients.
[image]

as an input y_train data, it has a list of 148 patient's diagnoses. It can be 'CN' 'MCI' and 'Dem', so it has 3 categories.

```
['CN',
 'MCI',
 'MCI',
 'CN',
 'MCI',
 'CN',
 'MCI',
...
```

So I made a model something like this.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(35,input_shape=(35, 51)))  #35 days, 51 features
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Which accuracy is really not that great, as you can see below it does not even pass validation accuracy 50%.

```
...
Epoch 200/200
2/2 [==============================] - 0s 131ms/step - loss: 0.0609 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9835 - val_loss: 3.2440 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.4667
```

Is there any way to improve this model? Or should I have to rebuild the model?

Comment: Is there a reason to expect your data to be predictive of the outcome? Can a physician use those observations to reliably make a correct diagnosis, for example?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a classic OVER-FITTING problem, the performances on the train set are really good and the performances on the validation set is lacking.
You can plot a training graph that displays the train and validation loss and accuracy of each epoch.
Example for such one: [link](https://machinelearningmastery.com/display-deep-learning-model-training-history-in-keras/)

```
history = model.fit(X, Y, validation_split=0.33, epochs=150, batch_size=10, verbose=0)
print(history.history.keys())
plt.plot(history.history['accuracy'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_accuracy'])
plt.title('model accuracy')
plt.ylabel('accuracy')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train', 'test'], loc='upper left')
plt.show()

plt.plot(history.history['loss'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'])
plt.title('model loss')
plt.ylabel('loss')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train', 'test'], loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

Another easy way to reduce the over-fitting is to reduce your model computational power/number or trained parameters, by reducing the number of neurons at each layer of your model.
For example:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(35,input_shape=(35, 51)))  #35 days, 51 features
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your model is **overfitting**. There are a couple ways to deal with this:

1.) The data you have is just 5k entries large. This is not suitable for Deep Learning algos which require a lot more data than this. You would be wise to use a ML algorithm for this data. Overfitting happens when the model you use is quite complicated for the data you have. Either use a ML algo or gather some more data if you want to use DL algos.

2.) You are using **accuracy** as a metric for a multiclass classification problem which is not advised. Try using a proper metric and see if it solves the problem.

3.) Another way to tackle this is as @niv dudovitch suggests. Reduce the complexity of the LSTM by reducing the no of parameters.

4.) You can try using Keras Tuner to tune the HP and see if it solves the problem.

5.) Try suing **Batch Normalization** instead of **Dropout**. If you really want to use Dropout then using a value of 0.5 is too large a value for such a small data.

Do lemme know if it works!

**Cheers!**

Comment: Do you have any suggestions for a proper metric? Brier score, log loss, Efron’s $R^2$ or McFadden’s $R^2$, for example?

Comment: Recall is a much better metric in the above case. Even F1 score can work.